# Chrome Packaged App: Auto-login user into webview

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, basic-authentication, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome Packaged App where users login to our App with an email and password and get an Auth Token back from our servers.

We later open a webview with our website in the webview. What would be the best way to auto-login the user into our website inside the webview?

I was thinking we could pass along the Auth token via the URL in the webview, but that probably isn't the most secure method. Are there other ways to pass info to the webview via the Chrome app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is the URL method insecure? Are you concerned about GET vs POST? If so, you should be using HTTPS anyway. The embedder-to-webview part is secure.

Other approaches are to executeScript the token into the webview, or to postmessage it in ether direction.

Comment: thanks @sowbug I thought exposing the user token in the URL may have been a security issue but we implemented https so its secure :). Thanks!